# Why does this container expand beyond the viewport?

Tags: html, css

I have a container that contains 4 colored blocks. I have styled the container to be 27px from the top of the viewport, and 2% from the left (this works). However, I want the right and bottom sides of this container to stop at the viewport, but instead it is going beyond it.

The blocks in the example below are thus slightly out of the viewport.

What am I doing wrong?

Please note that in the code below, the top row is almost 30 pixels higher than the bottom row because the container is not within the viewport completely.

I have a feeling it has to do with the wrapper container itself, specifically with the `height` and `width` as it is taking account of the margins that I gave it while still having a 100% height and width, but I am not sure.

Edit : When running the code below, it should be obvious there is a problem since the blocks are not all equal size due to the wrapper overflow.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}


#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

#square1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;      
  background-color: blue;
}

#square2 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;      
  background-color: yellow;
}

#square3 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;      
  background-color: green;
}

#square4 {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;      
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id='square1' class="square"></div>
  <div id='square2' class="square"></div>
  <div id='square3' class="square"></div>
  <div id='square4' class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `100%vw` is invalid...

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed it, though it does not solve the issue. That was just a syntax error.

Comment: well, your are adding a margin in addtion to the width/height so you will logically have an overflow. You need to decrease the width/height by the margin amount

Answer (score 2):

You can use `calc` to account for the margin:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  
}


#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100vw - 2%);
  height: calc(100vh - 27px);
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

#square1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  
  background-color: blue;
}

#square2 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  
  background-color: yellow;
}

#square3 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  background-color: green;
}

#square4 {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id='square1' class="square"></div>
  <div id='square2' class="square"></div>
  <div id='square3' class="square"></div>
  <div id='square4' class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The margins are *added*  to `width` and `heigth` properties, so 100vh height plus a margin of 27px will result in the bottom of the element being 27px below the viewport bottom. To avoid this, you can use `height: calc(100vh - 27px)`.